# Swift - WKWebView and itms-services (aka open popup)

Tags: swift, wkwebview

i've some troubles with `WKWebView` and `itms-services protocol`.

My app is composed by a single webview where i load correctly a web-page. Inside this web page, at certain time i would load an `itms-services` link, to install an app.

If i use Safari it's all ok: when i click on the link, Safari shows me an alert to ask me if the installation is ok.

But inside the `WKWebView`, this alert is not shown to me.

I've tried to implement `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)` method, without success.

This is my code.

```
private func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

        let requestURL: URL? = navigationAction.request.url
        let app = UIApplication.shared
        if let anURL = requestURL {
            if (requestURL?.scheme?.lowercased() == "itms-services") && app.canOpenURL(anURL) {
                if let anURL = requestURL {
                    app.openURL(anURL)
                    decisionHandler(.cancel)
                }
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        }

    }
```

The **itms-service URL** follows this pattern:

> itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.temporary.it/temporary.plist

Where i wrong? Is this the correct way?

Comment: did you found a solution for this problem......I've the same:(